# Cannot Find Module - Strong Loop

Tags: node.js, express, strongloop

I get this error when I try to update my app to the next version:

---

> Oct  7 12:32:57 carrduci_sys CARRDUCIsys[18970]: 2019-10-07T17:32:57.236Z pid:18970 worker:0 INFO supervisor started worker 16 (pid 19091)
>   Oct  7 12:32:57 carrduci_sys CARRDUCIsys[18970]: 2019-10-07T17:32:57.391Z pid:19091 worker:16 INFO strong-agent native addon missing, install a compiler
>   Oct  7 12:32:57 carrduci_sys CARRDUCIsys[18970]: 2019-10-07T17:32:57.392Z pid:19091 worker:16 INFO strong-agent v2.1.2 profiling app 'carrduci-sys-api' pid '19091'
>   Oct  7 12:32:57 carrduci_sys CARRDUCIsys[18970]: 2019-10-07T17:32:57.394Z pid:19091 worker:16 INFO strong-agent[19091] started profiling agent
>   Oct  7 12:32:57 carrduci_sys CARRDUCIsys[18970]: 2019-10-07T17:32:57.956Z pid:19091 worker:16 module.js:549
>   Oct  7 12:32:57 carrduci_sys CARRDUCIsys[18970]: 2019-10-07T17:32:57.957Z pid:19091 worker:16     throw err;
>   Oct  7 12:32:57 carrduci_sys CARRDUCIsys[18970]: 2019-10-07T17:32:57.957Z pid:19091 worker:16     ^
>   Oct  7 12:32:57 carrduci_sys CARRDUCIsys[18970]: 2019-10-07T17:32:57.957Z pid:19091 worker:16 Error: Cannot find module './imagenesFacturas.model'
>   Oct  7 12:32:57 carrduci_sys CARRDUCIsys[18970]: 2019-10-07T17:32:57.957Z pid:19091 worker:16     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:547:15)
>   Oct  7 12:32:57 carrduci_sys CARRDUCIsys[18970]: 2019-10-07T17:32:57.957Z pid:19091 worker:16     at Function.Module._load (module.js:474:25)
>   Oct  7 12:32:57 carrduci_sys CARRDUCIsys[18970]: 2019-10-07T17:32:57.957Z pid:19091 worker:16     at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
>   Oct  7 12:32:57 carrduci_sys CARRDUCIsys[18970]: 2019-10-07T17:32:57.957Z pid:19091 worker:16     at Module.module.**proto**.require (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/strong-agent/lib/agent.js:183:42)
>   Oct  7 12:32:57 carrduci_sys CARRDUCIsys[18970]: 2019-10-07T17:32:57.957Z pid:19091 worker:16     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
>   Oct  7 12:32:57 carrduci_sys CARRDUCIsys[18970]: 2019-10-07T17:32:57.957Z pid:19091 worker:16     at Object. (/home/carrduci/control-de-produccion-API/models/requisiciones/estatusRequisicion.model.js:3:30)
>   Oct  7 12:32:57 carrduci_sys CARRDUCIsys[18970]: 2019-10-07T17:32:57.957Z pid:19091 worker:16     at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
>   Oct  7 12:32:57 carrduci_sys CARRDUCIsys[18970]: 2019-10-07T17:32:57.958Z pid:19091 worker:16     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
>   Oct  7 12:32:57 carrduci_sys CARRDUCIsys[18970]: 2019-10-07T17:32:57.958Z pid:19091 worker:16     at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
>   Oct  7 12:32:57 carrduci_sys CARRDUCIsys[18970]: 2019-10-07T17:32:57.958Z pid:19091 worker:16     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
>   Oct  7 12:32:57 carrduci_sys CARRDUCIsys[18970]: 2019-10-07T17:32:57.958Z pid:19091 worker:16     at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
>   Oct  7 12:32:57 carrduci_sys CARRDUCIsys[18970]: 2019-10-07T17:32:57.958Z pid:19091 worker:16     at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
>   Oct  7 12:32:57 carrduci_sys CARRDUCIsys[18970]: 2019-10-07T17:32:57.958Z pid:19091 worker:16     at Module.module.**proto**.require (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/strongloop/node_modules/strong-agent/lib/agent.js:183:42)
>   Oct  7 12:32:57 carrduci_sys CARRDUCIsys[18970]: 2019-10-07T17:32:57.958Z pid:19091 worker:16     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
>   Oct  7 12:32:57 carrduci_sys CARRDUCIsys[18970]: 2019-10-07T17:32:57.958Z pid:19091 worker:16     at Object. (/home/carrduci/control-de-produccion-API/models/requisiciones/requisicion.model.js:5:33)
>   Oct  7 12:32:57 carrduci_sys CARRDUCIsys[18970]: 2019-10-07T17:32:57.958Z pid:19091 worker:16     at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)

---

Locally I have no problems. I run this in ubuntu server with this service:

```
[Unit]
Description=CARRDUCIsys server. Servidor de API.

[Service]
Type=simple
#Ejecucion del servicio. Es necesario definir el ambiente
#para que strong-pm genere los worker

ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/slc run /home/carrduci/control-de-produccion-API/
# WorkingDirectory=/home/carrduci/control-de-produccion-API/
Restart=always
RestartSec=10                       
# Restart service after 10 seconds if node service crashes
StandardOutput=syslog               
# Output to syslog
StandardError=syslog                
# Output to syslog
SyslogIdentifier=CARRDUCIsys
# User=nobody
# Group=nogroup
Environment=NODE_ENV=production
# Allow many incoming connections
LimitNOFILE=infinity

# Allow core dumps for debugging
LimitCORE=infinity

StandardInput=null


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The working version is the `v1.2.10`. I use git to maintenance the versions so I only need to do a `git pull` and `git checkout tagUpdate` to install new version.

Why do I get these errors?